# how to fetch configurable product from quote table and store it to database custom table?

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I'm trying to create a custom extension to store saved cart items.

For that I need to fetch configurable item from quote table and store them in a custom database table.

how to do that?

please help me..

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. Please add more details to your question, like which details you need to store to your custom table and on which action you want to populate your table. You can also add the code which you have tried so far.